# React unmount a Paypal button

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I have a Paypal button rendered with a Modal component. What is the proper way to unmount the Paypal Button without raising a clean up error?

Here is the implementation for the Dialog

```
<Drawer anchor="bottom" open={open} onClose={() => setStatus(false)}>
        <section className={classes.innerDrawer}>
          <h2 className={classes.innerDrawerTitle}>
            {loading ? '' : 'Checkout'}
          </h2>
          <PaypalButton
            ...props
          />
    </section>
  </Drawer>
```

And the button

```
const Button = paypal.Button.driver('react', { React, ReactDOM });

return (
    <Button
      env={PAYPAL_ENV}
      client={client}
      payment={(data, actions) => payment(data, actions)}
      onAuthorize={data => execute(data.payerID, data.paymentID)}
      style={{
        size: 'medium', // tiny, small, medium
        color: 'blue', // orange, blue, silver
        shape: 'rect', // pill, rect
      }}
    />
  );
```

The error message I get:

> Uncaught Error: No response from window - cleaned up

I do not get this error message when the un-mount is successful, which happens when I processed with a payment.

link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/r4zvkjm2kq

Comment: When do you get that error?

Comment: during `onClose` event. When I try to close the Drawer, which unmounts the paypal button

Comment: I see. Is the Drawer component developed by you? Or is it from a third-party library?

Comment: material ui component

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your issue, but I've tried to do the same code you're doing.

In this example, the PayPal button is mounted in the Drawer element, which is mounted after a button click. The Drawer is unmounted when you click in any place outside the drawer.

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
        open: false
      }
    }

    render () {      
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.setState({ open: true })}>Open Drawer</button>
          {
            this.state.open &&
            <Drawer anchor="left" open={true} onClose={() => this.setState({ open: false })}>
              <PayPalButton
                commit={this.state.commit}
                env={this.state.env}
                client={this.state.client}
                payment={(data, actions) => this.payment(data, actions) }
                onAuthorize={(data, actions) => this.onAuthorize(data, actions)}
                />
            </Drawer>
          }
        </div>
       )
    }
  }
```

Working demo: https://codepen.io/herodrigues/pen/gqQEgr

Comment: The problem with doing it this way the drawer is not controlling the state which losses its transition effects. I tried your code by removing `this.state.open &&`, and pass it to open `props`. The error surfaces.